# Unset values in bulk uploader in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Using bulkloader in App Engine, I can get properties set to certain values or to None (or null value).  I can also leave them unset if I don't include the property in bulkloader.yaml.

What I would like to do is set the property for some of the entities and leave the property unset for some other entities.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with the standard YAML configuration of the bulkloader. Note, though, that most model frameworks, including the Python one built in to App Engine, will create any missing properties when you first write a record with them, so there's not much point in going out of your way to leave them unspecified.

Comment: Perhaps they're expando properties.

Comment: Thanks. They are not expando properties. What I have is a StringListProperty. Looks like my only option (using YAML) is to set it to None.  In that case, the Datastore Viewer in the dashboard shows the property as <null>.  When a similar entity is created/stored from a request handler, omitting the property, the Datastore Viewer shows it as <missing>.  The latter entity doesn't appear in the index for that property.  Nick - Do you mean that once I create a record with that property set to a list, future records would have None/null for the property even if the property was missing at creation?

Comment: @cv12 If you create a model class that specifies that field, any records you save with it - new or existing - will have that field populated with null. List properties, though, are different, and won't show up at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [post_import_function](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuration_File_Reference_Details).

Let's say you have a string property called "notes" that should be omitted if empty:

```
def post_process_entity(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state):
  if instance['notes'] == '':
    del instance['notes']
  return instance
```

Comment: Drew - Where does this function definition go?  Is it just in some module on my path and I need to import the module in the python_preamble in the YAML file?